# How to name graphs in legend based on folder's name

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have plotted a graph for different sub-folders inside of a directory and I want to put a legend of each graph based on the name of the folder. I mean, the plot legend is being to be written according to the folder's name. The code for plotting is below:

```
from __future__ import division
import sys
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
import seaborn as sns
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats.kde import gaussian_kde


root = r'C:\Users\Hasan\Desktop\output\new our scenario\beta 15\test'
mean_cu=[]
my_list = os.listdir(root)
my_list =  [file for file in my_list if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root, file))]
for directory in my_list:
    CASES = [file for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(root, directory)) if file.startswith('config')]
    if len(CASES)==0:
        continue
    maxnum = np.max([int(os.path.splitext(f)[0].split('_')[1]) for f in CASES])
    CASES = ['configuration_%d.out' % i for i in range(maxnum)]
    mean_cu=[]
    for i, d in enumerate(CASES): 
        a = np.loadtxt(os.path.join(root, directory,d)).T 
        num = os.path.splitext(d)[0] 
        local_cu = np.abs(a[4])
        mean_curv.append(np.mean(local_cu))
        pdf = stats.norm.pdf(mean_cu)

    Time = np.arange(0,len(pdf))
    plt.plot(Time,pdf)
```

Comment: `plt.plot(Time, pdf, label=directory)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you have different graphs, and for each of them you want a different legend based on current folder. You can set legend by adding `label=directory` in plot method. Maybe you should first extract current folder (using split or different method) if you don't want full directory. That depends on your directory variable.

Consider following example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

legend1 = ["1", "2"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[4,5], "B":[6,7]})

for item in legend1:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(df["A"], df["B"], label=item)
    ax.legend(loc='upper left', frameon=False)
```

will result the following two graphs:

[image]
[image]

As you can see the only different is the legend, that was set by `legend1` list. You can make it your directories.